# Add Solver to Custom Ribbon to Show the Solver Parameters Dialog Box

Tags: excel

The goal is to add the standard Solver button to a custom ribbon.

Background: I have code that creates a Solver model automatically using custom ribbon buttons. However, before actually running Solver, I would like the user to verify, and modify as necessary, the automatically-generated Solver model - by showing the Solver Parameters dialog box. For the user's convenience, I want to put the standard Solver button on my custom ribbon.

Problems were:

1. Solver does not have an official Microsoft `msoImage` or `onAction` item. So, I created my own button that called `SolverOkDialog()`. BUT,...
2. `SolverOkDialog` does not display the Solver Parameters dialog box (at least I couldn't get it to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Big picture: Grab the icon and link from `Solver.xlam`.

1. Copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\SOLVER\SOLVER.XLAM` to a new file, `Solver.zip`.
2. Copy `….zip\customui\images\solver_icon.png` to someplace convenient.
3. Using your favorite ribbon xml editor(1) assign solver_icon to `RibbonX14`.
4. Insert the following code to your custom ribbon:

   ```
   <button id="btnSolver"
       getLabel="solver.xlam!GetSolverLabel"
       image="solver_icon"
       onAction="solver.xlam!MainEx"
       screentip="Solver"
       supertip="What-if analysis tool that finds the optimal value of a target cell by changing values in cells used to calculate the target cell."/>
   ```

I hope this helps someone.

If I am missing something, please let me know.

​(1)  I use Leaf Creations Office ​Ribbon Editor because it is simple, functions well, and it is Creative Commons compliant.